# How to setup pre-deploy hook for Sidekiq on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq, worker

I have a Ruby on Rails 6 application that needs to generate a report when a user submits a form that can take upwards of 5 minutes to generate. I am using Sidekiq to handle the generation of the report and send it to the user via email upon completion.

The issue I am running into is Heroku has a fixed 30-second process restart, so the worker isn't able to complete the report before the process is terminated. In the [Sidekiq documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#heroku), a proposed solution is to insert `Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new.each(&:quiet!)`in a pre-deployment hook.  However, I am unable to find any documentation on how to create such a hook.

So I have two questions:

1. Is this the best way to approach a long running process like this, and:
2. If so, how can I create and execute a pre-deployment hook

I am calling the worker in the controller like this:

```rb
Reporters::FinanceReportWorker.perform_async('report_method', email, start_date, end_date)
```

This is the worker class:

```rb
module Reporters
    class FinanceReportWorker
        include Sidekiq::Worker

        def perform(report_name, email, start_date, end_date)
            report = Reporters::FinanceReport.send(report_name, start_date, end_date)

            file_name = "#{report_name}_report_#{start_date}-#{end_date}.csv"

            csv = report
                    .map {|r| 
                        r.to_csv
                    }
                    .join "\n"
            ReportMailer.report_email(email, csv, file_name).deliver_now
        end
    end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've run into something similar with Heroku in the past.  My solution was to deal with the report in chunks.  Since you have a CSV file, you could spin up a worker literally for each line that should be written to the CSV.  I don't see the code in `FinanceReport.send` but I assume it dips the database for records between start and end and does a bunch of operations on that data.  Instead of doing the start and end, just do it by individual day, or even hour within a day, and fire off a worker for each chunk - appending to the same CSV.  Same end result, more code to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That might be the best way to go as I haven’t come across anything better.